# How to extract a name from a string in re

Tags: regex

I have a field that contains names structured as

> abc | lastname, firstname | xyz

How would I extract just the name given that it is always last name comma first name in between the pipe symbols?

```
df['colname'].str.extract(pat = '(^|\s.+,\s.+|$)')
```

It returns either blank or null values using this approach.

Comment: literal pipe symbols need to be escaped in a regex e.g. `(^\|\s.+,\s.+\|$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**Demo :**  [Here](https://regex101.com/r/eXp3eZ/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pipe symbols are actually within the string, and assuming your characters are either already a string ( or can be turned into a string by enclosing the characters within the quotation symbols), then using the stringr package with the str_extract() function can do the trick.  If the last name or first name are capitalized, this code would need to be changed.

Basically, just focus on matching the easiest character first, the comma. Then once you have a match, build your pattern up little by little and match more and more after that first match until you've matched what you wanted.

```
library(stringr)

names <- "abc | lastname, firstname | xyz"    # create a string
print(names)     

str_extract(names, "[a-z]*, [a-z]*")          # extract the names


[1] "abc | lastname, firstname | xyz"      # printed string

'lastname, firstname'                      # output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a capturing group and a negated character class `[^...]` to match any char except those which are listed.

The value is in the first capturing group.

Note to escape the pipe outside of the character class.

```
^[^\r\n|]*\|\s+([^\r\n,|]+,[^\r\n,|]+)\|
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n|]*` Match 0+ times not a pipe or newline
- `\|\s+` Match a pipe and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\r\n,|]+` Match 1+ times not a comma, pipe or newline
  - `,` Match the comma
  - `[^\r\n,|]+` Match 1+ times not a comma, pipe or newline
- `)` Close group
- `\|` Match a pipe

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7DBitP/1)

The `.+` part in your pattern  or `[^\r\n,|]`  will also match an empty string as the name.

You might for example first match a char a-zA-Z or specify what you want to allow to prevent an empty first or lastname.

```
^[^\r\n|]*\|\s+([A-Za-z][^\r\n,|]*,\s*[A-Za-z][^\r\n,|]*)\|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ecz4Hn/1)